# ¿Por qué este fallo al sustituir concat() por merge()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

En el enlace [descarga de ficheros][1], se encuentran los ficheros nesarios para comprobar la ejecución de estos scripts.

Mi objetivo es acceder a todos los archivos de un mismo tipo, alojados en una carpeta, e importar sus datos dentro de un DataFrame único.

Lo consigo iterando sobre una lista de DataFrames y utilizando la función **merge**, de la siguiente manera.

```
    import glob 
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
    path = "/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Paso_Peregrino/Ficheros_Yahoo_csv/"
    
    """Importa los datos de los ficheros csv de una dirección determinada"""
    filenames = glob.glob(path + "*.csv") 
    dfs = []
    nombres = []
    for filename in filenames: 
        nombre = filename[len(path):-4] 
        nombres.append(nombre)    
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
        
    dfs = iter(dfs)
    df_final = next(dfs)
    for df_ in dfs:
        df_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Date')
    df_final = df_final.set_index("Date")
    df_final.columns = nombres
    df_final 

El resultado devuelto, como se ve en la imágen, es correcto.

[![devolución con merge][2]][2]

Pero hay una advertencia de posibles problemas futuros utilizando la función **merge**. Para evitar este problema, lo intento con el mismo script, pero eliminando la iteración y el merge, y aplicando la función **concat**. El script queda así.

# Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
os.chdir('/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2022/Gestion-Conservadora-de-Activos_Financieros/Datos/Ficheros_R4')

"""Importa los datos de los ficheros csv de una dirección determinada"""
filenames = glob.glob("*.csv") 
dfs = []
nombres = []

def leer_nombres():
    lista_ficheros = os.listdir()
    lista_nombres = [] 
    for fichero in lista_ficheros:
        lista_nombres.append(fichero[:-5])
    dicc = dict(zip(lista_nombres ,lista_ficheros))    
    return lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc

lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc = leer_nombres()

for nombre,file in dicc.items():   
    data = pd.read_csv(file,  decimal  =",", sep='\t', na_values = ["nan"], parse_dates = True)
    data = data.set_index("Date")         
    data.rename(columns={"Close":nombre}, inplace=True )
    dfs.append(data)

lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc = leer_nombres()

    
#dfs = iter(dfs)
total = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
total
```

Me devuelve

```
    EPS     DedaloP     NexuxP  TrueValu    Acati   ValorRelativ    GlobalAllocationP
0   10.000  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   10.001  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   10.002  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   10.002  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   10.003  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
19450   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     10.756
19451   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     10.755
19452   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     10.755
19453   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     10.754
19454   NaN     NaN     NaN
```

¿Donde está el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución con concat() es, sustituir la sentencia

```
total = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

por la sentencia.

```
total = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner')
```

De este modo, la concatenación se realiza a lo largo del eje 1(eje horizontal) y considera solamente las etiquetas (fechas) comunes.
El script completo quedaría así.

```
import os
# Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
os.chdir('/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2022/Gestion-Conservadora-de-Activos_Financieros/Datos/Ficheros_R4')

"""Importa los datos de los ficheros csv de una dirección determinada"""
filenames = glob.glob("*.csv") 
dfs = []
nombres = []

def leer_nombres():
    lista_ficheros = os.listdir()
    lista_nombres = [] 
    for fichero in lista_ficheros:
        lista_nombres.append(fichero[:-5])
    dicc = dict(zip(lista_nombres ,lista_ficheros))    
    return lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc

lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc = leer_nombres()

for nombre,file in dicc.items():   
    data = pd.read_csv(file,  decimal  =",", sep='\t', na_values = ["nan"], parse_dates = True)
    data = data.set_index("Date")         
    data.rename(columns={"Close":nombre}, inplace=True )
    dfs.append(data)

lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc = leer_nombres()

total = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner')
total
```

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda ser correcta le hace falta explicar el motivo por el cual es una solución válida. Por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega detalles y una explicación.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explicación

Tu error es algo complejo, pues tiene relación con los iteradores. Un iterador es un objeto especial que conforme se va recorriendo devuelve valores. Cuando un iterador termina de recorrerse, se dice que se consume y no devuelve nada más. Estoy seguro que entenderás mejor como funciona un iterador leyendo el paso a paso que hice sobre lo que hace tu código.

1. Creas la lista con los DataFrames.
2. Conviertes esa lista en un iterador.
3. El bucle for consume el primer item del iterador. Queda por devolver nada más el DataFrame df2.
4. La función pd.concat termina por consumir el resto del iterador. Por lo que la linea de codigo que hace este paso se vuelve funcionalmente equivalente a ejecutar `df_final = pd.concat([df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)`
5. Como ya el iterador no tiene más que devolver, termina el bucle for.

Por si no entiendes algo del paso a paso que hice, tu código se volvió funcionalmente equivalente a.

```
df_ = dfs[0]
df_final = pd.concat(dfs[1:], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

#### Solución

No necesitas usar ningún bucle for. El primer argumento de pd.concat puede ser, entre otras cosas, una lista de n DataFrames, por lo que tampoco hace falta convertir la lista en un iterador.

```
dfs = []
dfs.append(df1)
dfs.append(df2)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df_final
```

Comment: @ Danate S. He modificado en la pregunta todo el contenido, para que se vea el problema que se manifiesta al intentar aplicar concat,como tu muy bien sugieres. No acabo de entender por qué, a diferencia de con el ejemplo simple, en este caso real algo falla.

Comment: Continúo con el problema. He modificado la pregunta para incluir el último secript en el que incorporé tu sugerencia. El resultado sigue sin ser correcto. Agradeceré eches un vistazo.

Comment: Esta ha sido la solución: "df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, join='inner')"